# Merge single-file and keep author of change in git

Tags: git

A developer made a change in his branch `foo-branch`, which contains 2 modified files

```
commit: 8ab45aa
        + foo.txt (modified)
        + bar.txt (modified)
```

As far as I understood, **[git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)** is used to merge given commits. But is it possible to use only a partial commit? In this case I only want to merge `foo.txt` of commit **8ab45aa**

**Important:**

There are several questions about this topic on SO, but my requirement is to keep the author of the changes. Several other solutions overwrite it with the user making the merge.

Comment: Important: commits don't store changes; they store full snapshots. The author of the commit is whatever is in the commit's metadata as the author. When you look at a commit and "see" a change, what you're really looking at is not the commit itself, but rather **a comparison of the commit's parent's snapshot with the commit's snapshot**. So when you cherry-pick a commit, there's a lot going on behind the scenes. You *can* do what you want (see eftshift0's answer for one method), just be sure you know what you're doing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
git cherry-pick the-ID-of-revision
git checkout HEAD~1 -- file-we-dont-want-to-modify
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Comment: You probably don't want to `git rm` the entire file—you probably want to put it back the way it was, instead. Often a little easier: `git cherry-pick -n <hash>`; adjust the index and work-tree contents with `git reset HEAD -- the-other-file`; `git commit`. To do this without the `-n` step first, replace `git rm` with `git checkout HEAD~2`.

Comment: Oh, @torek, that is a good catch. The file was _modified_, not deleted. Let me adjust my recipe with how I would do it.

Comment: Better, but `HEAD~1` is still wrong because that commit has the updated file... :-)

Comment: Ah, what? `git checkout HEAD~1 -- bar.txt` will have bar.txt _without the changes that are coming from the cherry-pick operation_... in other words, after `git commit --amend` you will get only foo.txt modified, bar.txt will be as in the parent of the revision, so no changes on that file.

Comment: Oh, duh, right, you haven't made a second commit yet (and when you do it will just shove this one aside). Sorry, working on several things simultaneously. Will delete that other comment in a bit.

Comment: Oh, man.... leave it for history's sake... `I was able to correct @torek once`. Can I use it in my resume?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance that your master (or the branch that will be merged to) can be modified in a way you add an extra space to the end of the lines of the code you want to keep?

That way you'll force a conflict then you can keep the changes you want, and in the git logs you will still see the changes of the developer

Comment: Uh, that is actually a cool idea!! Can't recall if git also retains authors if more than one conflict appears in one file

Comment: It will because the history of each line is taken separately. And even if multiple authors conflict on the same line, you solve these kind of conflicts one at a time, so yes, it will be logged

Comment: @DanielStephens: again, the author of *any* commit is, well, the *author*, stored in the commit. This is almost an arbitrary string. To see how Git stores them, run `git cat-file -p HEAD` at any time: that will show you the current commit's metadata. There are no conflicts here: the commit has a snapshot, and snapshots don't *have* conflicts, they're just snapshots.

Comment: Makes sense! Opened a few other questions for git the other days (which got almost all answered). Coming from Perforce, the git concept is great, but conflicting on so many levels with Perforces way of structuring a project

Comment: Actually working on a solution how to convert Perforce to git (like what tomtom did), but `git p4` is too limited so I am exploring other manual solutions at the moment to write a converter that works for me and our depot